# Creating shared library fails in Git Bash shell using Makefile

Tags: makefile

I am trying to create shared library i.e. .so from C++ code using Git Bash shell in Windows 10.
I use Makefile for compiling C++ code in Windows 10. Running make through Git bash shell.
Code compiles without any issue and creates object files without fail.
But it fails while creating .so file throwing following error. Following is part of Makefile in which target VLIB_SHARED_LIBRARY is causing this error.

```
VLIB_SO_DIR = .
VLIB_SHARED_LIBRARY = $(VLIB_SO_DIR)/libvxxx.so
CXX = g++

CXXFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++11 -O2 -D_7ZIP_ST -fPIC
LDFLAGS = -shared

OBJECT_FILES = a.o b.o c.o d.o .. z.o

all: init $(VLIB_SHARED_LIBRARY )

release: init $(VLIB_SHARED_LIBRARY )

$(VLIB_SHARED_LIBRARY): $(OBJECT_FILES) \n
        $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(VLIB_SHARED_LIBRARY) $(OBJECT_DIR)/*.o

process_begin: CreateProcess(C:\Program, C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe -c "g++ -shared -o C:/XXXX_YYYY/bbbb/bin_linux/libyyyy.so C:/XXXX_YYYY/bbbb/bin_linux/obj/*.o", ...) failed.
make (e=193): Error 193
```

Same Makefile works fine in actual Linux Ubuntu OS but fails in Windows 10.
How to fix this error ?

Comment: You need to show us the rule or makefile.  This looks extremely bizarre to me.  One thing to note is that using pathnames with whitespace in them with make and makefiles is a sure recipe for tons of problems, and should be avoided.  If you can't avoid them, then you at least have to quote the paths properly.  Also please use correct StackOverflow formatting in your question (paste as code samples, not bold).

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git. "Git bash" is a port of bash that Git *uses*, but it's not *part of* Git. I updated your tags. Maybe someone who reads the [tag:git-bash] items will know what this CreateProcess issue is.

Comment: @MadScientist Updated with excerpts of Makefile which is causing issues. I am aware that Makefile is very sensitive for whitespace but I am sure that there no such things in makefile. It is just final call to create shared library is failing.

Comment: @torek It is bash shell provided by Git in which has mingw64 library with c++ compiler and make utility. I am just using it to prepare shared library for linux. Instead of using Linux machine, I want to create shared library and windows DLL on same machine.

Comment: (Maybe this is clearer: git-bash is bundled into the Git-for-Windows distribution, but it has nothing to do with Git itself.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I suggested whitespace issues in my comment above is that the error message CLEARLY shows that it's a whitespace problem:

```
CreateProcess(C:\Program, C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe ...
```

There is a space in this path to `sh.exe`, and the first argument printed here `C:\Program` quite clearly shows that the path has been truncated at the space.

I thought maybe your makefile was setting `SHELL` to some value but it doesn't appear to be.  All I can suggest is either (a) remove `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` from your `%Path%`, or (b) re-install Git into a path that doesn't contain whitespace so that you don't hit this problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I changed installation location from C:\Program Files to C:\ and it worked without any issue.  Marking your comment as Answer